# QMainWindow not receiving keyPressEvent, even with event filter

Tags: qt, events, qt5, qmainwindow, eventfilter

I'm trying to design an image viewer application where I use a QGraphicsView to display my images. I want to enable the user to use the arrow keys to open the next/previous image, but my QGraphicsView is always consuming my keyPressEvent. I would like these events to be handled by my QMainWindow class instead. I realize this is a common issue, and apparently I can solve it by installing an event filter and/or ensuring that my QMainWindow can have focus. I have done both, but so far the only thing I have done is to not let the QGraphicsView get the event, but it still does not propagate to the QMainWindow. So far I've implemented the `eventFilter` method in my `QMainWindow` class and installed it on my `QGraphicsView` object.

**QMainWindow class**

```cpp
IVMainWindow::IVMainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setWindowTitle("ImageViewer++");
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);  // Enabled the QMainWindow to get focus

    m_image_widget = new IVImageWidget();
    m_image_widget->installEventFilter(this);  // Install event filter on QGraphicsView
    setCentralWidget(m_image_widget);

    resize(QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->availableSize() * 3 / 5);

    // For DEBUG purpose
    loadImage("res/image.png");

    createMenuBar();
    createToolBar();
}

/**
 * Filters out arrow key presses.
 */
bool IVMainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        auto *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        int key = keyEvent->key();
        // Return true to reject the key-presses
        return (key == Qt::Key_Left || key == Qt::Key_Right || key == Qt::Key_Up || key == Qt::Key_Down);
    } else {
        // standard event processing
        return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
}

//Never gets to this point, unless I explicitly give it focus by clicking on some other widget than the QGraphicsView...
void IVMainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if (event->key() == Qt::RightArrow) {
        m_logger.Debug("Right arrow pressed.");
    } else if (event->key() == Qt::LeftArrow) {
        m_logger.Debug("Left arrow pressed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your question the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445997/qgraphicsview-and-eventfilter)? (I know it's for Qt4 though.)

Comment: @JarMan not sure. I tried installing the event filter on the viewport and to `setFocusProxy(0)` but neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process the event in the event filter, it is ok to call QMainWindow::eventFilter for sanity but it do not
process the event as an incoming event, so the event handlers will not be called.

```
bool IVMainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        auto *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        int key = keyEvent->key();
        // Return true to reject the key-presses
        if  (key == Qt::Key_Left || key == Qt::Key_Right || key == Qt::Key_Up || key == Qt::Key_Down)
        {
            //process event here somehow, or instruct your class to do it later
            return true; //filter the event
        }
    } else {
        // standard event processing
        return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
}

//This will only be called for the 'real' events, the ones that eventually are received by the main window
void IVMainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if (event->key() == Qt::RightArrow) {
        m_logger.Debug("Right arrow pressed.");
    } else if (event->key() == Qt::LeftArrow) {
        m_logger.Debug("Left arrow pressed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm yeah thanks, that works! I thought I could redirect the event but explicitly calling the `keyPressEvent` method works too.